# Standard Web Form - POST method not working when adding hidden input name _token ( Laravel 5.5 + VueJS 2X )

Tags: html, laravel, vuejs2, forms, http-post

I searched so much and I tried so many things but i didn't get solution.

I hope can given answer and find solution for this issue .

Im using Laravel 5.5 and Vuejs 2.

I have ordinary web form trying top send POST data .

But my form not sending POST method when Im adding there CSRF token .

My raw codes samples here...

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.100/login" method="POST">
                                <input name="_token" type="hidden" v-model="csrfToken">
                                <button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
                              </form>
```

it's looking on browser...

```
<form data-v-1b610de5="" action="http://192.168.1.100/login" method="POST"><input data-v-1b610de5="" name="_token" type="hidden" value="3jQ5KJV9TiCcTXF0fICpXYgX0C1irPpdHLkZWiAg"> <button data-v-1b610de5="" type="submit"> SUBMIT </button></form>
```

Actually all is looks like OKAY...

I tried all all all things..

There is a problem name of hidden input or value ....

When Im changing value any for example writing "Chuk Norris" sending POST data well.

But real CSRF data - not sending POST . Refreshing self .. Not going to action address .

I tried this on CHROME and MOZILLA too.

Is there any idea or solution for this ? Why not sending POST data ?

GET is sending.... But I need POST ...

Thank you !!!

Comment: What's the problem? What happens if you post the form? What error do you get or what's not working?

Comment: there is no any ERROR ...

Just refreshing page, not going to action adress or not POSTING data to there if CSRF value is true...

If I'm changing value of _token (with wrong CSRF value ) , then POSTING data ...

 there is ordinary WEB FORM, really interesting

If Im changing method GET, working this form...

Answer (score 0):

I found problem and solution...

But interesting...

I used always my local IP for testin, when i used domain address ( I add fake domain on hosts file ) then, tried , sending POST data ...

All is okay now , thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

actually there was a different problem... not IP or URL ..

let csrf_token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
window.csrf = csrf_token.content

i get CSRF data like this on HTML . I don't know what happening there...

Then i try to store directly local storage csrf then get from local.Storage and then worked well ....

have a nice day !